# Sum with binomial coefficients: $\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose 2k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients

I'm repeating material for test and I came across the example that I can not do. How to calculate this sum:
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose 2k}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$(1+1)^{2n}= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}{2n\choose k}$$
$$(1-1)^{2n}= \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(-1)^k{2n\choose k}$$

Add them together.

**OR** Second solution:

You can use the formula

$${2n\choose 2k}={2n-1\choose 2k}+{2n-1\choose 2k-1}$$ to prove that

$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{2n\choose 2k}=\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1}{2n-1\choose k}$$

Comment: I like first solution :-)

Answer (score 2):

$\binom{2n}{2k}$ is the number of subsets of $\{1,\dots,2n\}$ of size $2k$. When you sum these binomial coefficients over all $k$ from $0$ through $n$, you’re counting the number of subsets of $\{1,\dots,2n\}$ whose cardinalities are even. For $n>0$ exactly half of the subsets have even cardinalities, so the sum is $\frac12(2^{2n})=2^{2n-1}$.

Clearly $\{1\}$ has one even subset, $\varnothing$, and one odd subset, $\{1\}$. Suppose that $\{1,\dots,n\}$ has $2^{n-1}$ even and $2^{n-1}$ odd subsets. Now look at the $2^{n+1}$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$. Half of them are $2^n$ subsets of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, of which $2^{n-1}$ are even and $2^{n-1}$ are odd. The other $2^n$ subsets all contain $n+1$. The even ones are obtained by adding $n+1$ to an odd subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, so there are $2^{n-1}$ of them. The odd ones are obtained by adding $n+1$ to an even subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, so there are $2^{n-1}$ of them as well. Thus, $\{1,\dots,n+1\}$ has $2^{n-1}+2^{n-1}=2^n$ even subsets and the same number of odd subsets.

This does fail for $n=0$, since the empty set has only one subset, itself, and therefore has one even and no odd subsets. In that case $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}=\binom00=1\;.$$

Comment: This is beautiful what  the combinatorial interpretation can do.. without counting :-)

Comment: The counting is probably easier if you think instead of binary sequences of length $2n$ (these are exactly the subsets). Erasing the last digit of a binary string is a bijection between the binary strings of length 2n with even number of 1's and all the binary strings of length 2n-1...

Comment: @N.S.: Matter of taste. It’s just about six of one and half a dozen of the other, but for elementary presentations I prefer my version.

Answer (score 2):

from binomial theorem we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}x^{i}=(1+x)^{2m}$$

for $x=1$ and $x=-1$ we get

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k}+\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k-1}=2^{2m}$$

$$\sum_{i=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{i}(-1)^{i}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k}-\sum_{k=1}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k-1}=0$$
suming these equations we get
$$2\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k}=2^{2m}$$ finally

$$\sum_{k=0}^{2m}\binom{2m}{2k}=2^{2m-1}$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> With $\ds{n \in \mathbb{N}_{\ \geq\ 0}}$:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{2n \choose 2k} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose k}{1 + \pars{-1}^{k} \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose k}1^{k} +
{1 \over 2}\sum_{k = 0}^{2n}{2n \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\pars{1 + 1}^{2n} + {1 \over 2}\bracks{1 + \pars{-1}}^{2n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{2^{2n - 1} + {1 \over 2}\,\delta_{n0}}
\\ & \
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Using line integrals: taking $r>1$,
$$
\eqalign{2\pi i\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{2k}
&= \sum_{k=0}^n\int_{|z|=r}\frac{(z + 1)^{2n}}{z^{2k+1}}\,dz
 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty\int_{|z|=r}\frac{(z + 1)^{2n}}{z^{2k+1}}\,dz
 = \int_{|z|=r}\frac{(z + 1)^{2n}}z\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac1{z^{2k}}\,dz\cr
&= \int_{|z|=r}\frac{(z + 1)^{2n}}z\,\frac1{1 - 1/z^2}\,dz
 = \int_{|z|=r}\frac{z(z + 1)^{2n-1}}{z-1}\,dz = 2\pi i\,2^{2n-1}.
}
$$