# How to find the General expression of $\sum_{k=0}^ {\lfloor n/3\rfloor} {n \choose 3k}$

Tags: combinatorics, complex-numbers, summation, summation-method

Well as the title says I'm having problems trying to derive a general expression for this sum which involves cubic roots of unity

$$\sum_{k=0}^ {\lfloor \frac n 3\rfloor} {n \choose 3k}$$

Need help guys!

Comment: I read this http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142260/sum-of-every-kth-binomial-coefficient?rq=1 but I have never come across the second sum they mentioned :s

Comment: As we need $3k,$  put $1,w,w^2$ where $w^3=1$  in $$(1+x)^n$$ and add

Comment: I still can't see where the $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$ comes from :s

Comment: Note that ${n\choose 3k} = 0$ by definition if $3k > n$ so the sum of ${n\choose 3k}$ over all integers $k$ is the same as the sum over all integers satisfying $k \leq \frac{n}{3}$. This is the likely reason why the upper-limit is taken as $\lfloor n/3 \rfloor$.

Comment: Now I see it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint:

The binomial theorem gives $f(x) = (1+x)^n = \sum_{i = 0} \binom{n}{i} x^i$.

Now if $\zeta$ is a cubic root of unity, consider an appropriate linear combination of $f(1), f(\zeta)$ and $f(\zeta^2)$.  Since $1 + \zeta + \zeta^2 = 0$, you should be able to make all but the threeven terms in the sum cancel.